# Can I replace a Shimano MF-Z012 (freewheel) with a MF-TZ510?

Tags: freewheel

Can I replace a (6-speed) Shimano [MF-Z012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUStN.jpg) with a (6-speed) [MF-TZ500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDDd4.jpg) or MF-TZ510 freewheel?

Bonus question: apart from the "T" both models seem to belong to a related series. What does the "T" mean?

Comment: The T makes me think of Tourney, the Shimano product tier, see the TZ510 [product page](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tourney/MF-TZ510-7.html), though that is a little speculative/assumption. I'd be more intrigued to know what the Z is for, though that seems to be a longstanding inclusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these models are freewheels not cassettes. They are for the most part interchangeable. The only area of concern would be the size of the largest cog. Too large a difference from you original model may necessitate a longer or shorter chain. You may also need to make some small adjustments get the shifting optimized.

Comment: I'm learning something new every day ... didn't know up until now that there are those two different systems. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOzjiDwvIss